# mkdir: bad message

Tags: linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке создать директорию я получаю bad message. Что означает это ошибка? Место есть, диск - несколько терабайт, на примонтированном разделе в корне примерно 800к папок с 80 миллионами файлов. Ошибку стало выдавать недавно

Comment: Никогда не вставляйте  картинку в вопрос вместо текста. У вас опечатка в команде.

Comment: звучит как ошибка в ФС, `fsck` прогонял? какая вообще ФС? а учитывая количества файлов можетбыть исчерпание инодов, `df -i` для уверенности... и да, вставляй текст, а не картинки...